# How can I check if an ID belongs to a user or a group?

Tags: rest

I've got a SharePoint list with a field where authorized users and/or groups are listed. I know I can use CanCurrentUserViewMembership to check if the user belongs to a specific group, but if the ID I pass belongs to a user I get an Internal Server Error.

Is there a way to check whether the ID belongs to a person or group before making this call? Taking into consideration that I'm doing this on a loop, so a lot of calls are being made.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a separate call to a function get all group ID's in an array before calling your current function.

Inside your current function, check if the user/group ID is available in array - then its group else user.

Pseudo code

```
// Get all Group ID
var groupID[] = *array of IDS*

// Current Code 

....
....
     // Check if ID is in gorupID[]
....
....
```